# Web Folder is accessible on local host but not found on web server

Tags: php, server, permissions, webserver, cpanel

I was working on my site in php using xampp server. everything was going fine and great. i created the pages styled with css, functionalized with javascript and stored data with mysql. everything gone fine. when i decided to upload it to web server it didn't work well. on the very first page it didn't load css.

In the root directory i have only three files `index.php`, `log-in.php` and `connect.php`. css, js and every other files and folders are located in dashboard folder in root directory.

when i access website it shows the root `index.php` with no css because css files are in `dashboard/` and when i access `domain.com/dashboard` it says

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle 
the request.
```

I changed the files and folders permission on cpanel but that didn't work either.

`This is directory structure`
[image: This is directory structure]
`root index file`

[image: root index file]

`dashboard not accessible`
[image: dashboard not accessible]
`should look like this`
[image: should look like this]

I hope somebody has explanation to this problem that why it is occurring and what is the solution.

Thank You...

Comment: The dashboard folder is called `Dashboard`. Linux is case -sensitive.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I capitalized `Dashboard` didn't work either. yesterday it was giving `Not found` error but today it is giving only a blank page.. whether it is `dashboard` or `Dashboard`. I also replaced inside code path of dashboard and changed them accordingly but no luck.